# Visual C++: automatic include refactoring when moving/renaming files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, include, refactoring

I just moved from CodeBlocks to Visual Studio 2013, and this is my first time using VS2013. My CodeBlocks project used virtual folders for structure, while keeping all the "physical" files in the same directory (I know, I know...) So I just spent an incredibly tedious 45 minutes replicating that structure with actual folders, creating folders and moving files around. The worst part was that, for each and every header file, I had to run a search-and-replace command like the following to update its path: #include "ObjectPtrArray.h" => #include "Structures/ObjectPtrArray.h"

This is a fairly large project (120+ source files), and I'm going to be doing much, much more refactoring over the coming days. A lot of that will include renaming classes, splitting them, creating new folders, moving files from folder to folder, and such. So is there any way I can automate this process? i.e. if I have a header file Tiles/SceneMap.h and I move it to Graphics/Tiles/SceneMap.h, can Visual Studio (or an extension for it) automatically update all of the includes that reference this file, without me having to run search-and-replace manually?

I do have ReSharper, but when I right click on a file the Refactor menu is blank. Is there another extension that I can use which would do this (preferably not conflicting with ReSharper?)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Maybe take a look at Visual Assist X. I'm not sure if it can do exactly that but it does have several refactoring features. There is a free trial version (otherwise it's insanely expensive).

Comment: I actually just downloaded Visual Assist X, it seems to handle file renaming within the same directory but not moving files from folder to folder.

Comment: Also, I just found out VC++ seems to support virtual folders, in the form of filters... derp. So one "solution" would be to have everything in one physical folder, use filters for organization, and VAX for renames. But a better solution that preserves the physical layout of the project on disk would be great.

Comment: Another solution is to leave the source code alone, but add new directories to the include search path.  VAX has limited rename and no structural refactoring support (moving files around in the directory structure and fixing up the projects and/or files that reference those files).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tool that tries to correct your `#include ""` statements throughout your codebase. There are some extra options that allow you to rewrite `#include <>` to `#include ""` directives if the included file is actually from your code (as opposed to a system header).

Please read carefully what it does before using it. Feel free to try it as much as you want in dry-run mode (the default).

https://github.com/mcourteaux/sfincludes